# Trying to make a simple random number generator

Tags: python, random

I'm super new to python and I'm just trying to make a very simple random number generator function, but nothing seems to be working, and python just gives me an error every time. Could anyone help with this?

```
def roll_dice(num):
    return random.randint(1, num)

roll_dice(6)
```

Error Message:

```
NameError: name 'random' is not defined
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow ! Remember to put the error message in the question so that readers can try to debug your code. In your case I guess you just forgot to import the "random" module. Insert `import random` at the top of your code and it should be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although random comes with python itself (you don't need to install it)

but to use it you need to import it

```
import random # you need to import random
def roll_dice(num):
    return random.randint(1, num)

roll_dice(6)
```

`import` means : Python code in one module gains access to the code in another module by the process of importing it.